# how to pass parameters to web service when click on button in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am new to Flutter development. could you please any one tell me how to pass parameters to url when click on button. Thank you.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:minerva_admin/Homescreen.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


    class Login extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return new LoginState();
      }

    }


    class LoginState extends State<Login> {

      final TextEditingController _userController = new TextEditingController();

      final String url = "http://192.155.1.40:8088/restaurants";
      List data;



      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Minerva Money"),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),

          backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          body: new Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                //image/profi

                //form
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      new TextField(
                        controller: _userController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter Email/Mobile Number',
                            icon: new Icon(Icons.person)
                        ),
                      ),


                      new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.5)), //add padding

                      new Center(
                        // Login button

                        child: new RaisedButton(

                             onPressed: (){
                          getSWData(_userController.toString());
                        },
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: new Text("Login",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16.9))),


                        // Clear button


                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                ), //form ends here

                new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0)),


              ],
            ),
          ),


        );
      }
Future<String> getSWData(String email) async {
        var res = await http.get(
            Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
        print("response" + "$url");
        setState(() {
          var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

          // data = resBody["restos_cities"];
          print("response" + "$resBody");
        });
        return "succees";
      }

    }
```

can any one explain me how to send textfield data in "email" parameter to web service when click on buton to get the data. Thank you in advance. I added  http: ^0.11.3+16 in my pubspec file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to enable the `onPressed` attribute of your `RaisedButton`. There you have to call some function passing your email parameter which is in your defined `TextEditingController`:

```
onPressed: () {
  yourFunction(_userController.text.toString());
},
```

Then, implement in 'yourFunction' your webservice call with the captured parameter from the `TextField`

Comment: Thank you for the response. How to pass the parameters to url?. i edited my code

Comment: Usually 'get' operations append the parameters at the end of the url (a simple concatenation), but i don't know the format since the specification of your webservice is unknown to me. You should call 'getSWData(_userController.text.toString())' instead of 'getSWData(_userController.toString())' in order to get the input text properly